# Is monotonic_clock available in

Tags: c++, std, c++-chrono

I tried every standard from C++98 to GNU++14, but I always get:

```
No member named 'monotonic_clock' in namespace 'std::chrono'
```

My code is:

```
#include <chrono>
std::chrono::monotonic_clock::time_point timePoint;
```

Do I need to include additional headers?

Comment: You used -std=c++11 flag or wtv right?

Comment: If I set XCode to use C++11 is it not equivalent?

Comment: `monotonic_clock` was renamed (and never existed in the official FD). See the dupe question for details.

Comment: You are right, put a define for that and it works. Thanks.

Comment: @aledalgrande Use an alias template instead.

Comment: Oh didn't know about that, pretty cool.